# how to call a ui component of a fragment from another fragment Android

Tags: java, android, set, fragment

how can I call a ui component defined in a fragment A from a fragment B. I have declared textview in fragment A and I want to set a calculated value in textview present in fragment B.I use java to develop the app. Greetings

Comment: Did you read the [guide to communicating between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)?

Comment: Using LiveData on a shared activity level ViewModel is probably the best approach to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, directly.  There's a couple of ways you can do this, but Fragment A and Fragment B shouldn't know about each other.  They're independent.  Instead, Fragment A should define an interface it calls when an event (such as changing the value of its textview) occurs.  This can be a callback function in an interface, a message bus, an Observable, a view model, or a variety of other mechanisms.  In Fragment B, you have an API that sets the value.  This can be a function call, passing in an observable you subscribe to which sets the value, passing in a message bus that will tell it when the value changes, using a ViewModel and subscribing to updates to that, etc.

Then the Activity is in charge of wiring up the interface on A to effect the interface on B.  Which way you choose depends on what technologies the rest of your app uses.